# copy to release repository

Tags: cloudbees

I wonder what would be the easiest way to copy a build result with a simple ant script to the release repository. I want this to be triggered manually (not on everey build). Could you please give me any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

deployment to CloudBees release repository require a webDav client and repository credentials, so the simplest way from an ant script is to use [maven-ant-tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html)

```
<artifact:deploy file="target/my-project-1.0.jar">
  <remoteRepository url="dav:https://repository-nicolas.forge.cloudbees.com/release/"
                    id="cloudbees-private-repository" />      
  <pom refid="mypom"/>
</artifact:deploy>
```

Using id "cloudbees-private-repository" repository credentials will be picked-up from default maven settings.xml that is set on your account with forge crendentials, so you don't have to pass them. You also can pass them as parameters :

```
<remoteRepository url="dav:https://repository-nicolas.forge.cloudbees.com/release/">
  <authentication username="..." privateKey="..."/>
</remoteRepository>
```